Parsing xml with minidom
Using Python, I am trying to parse an XML file that includes the following structure:
<channel>
    <index>1</index>
    <values>
        <entry>
            <key>SRV_PARAM_CH_ENABLED</key>
            <value xsi:type="xs:boolean" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">false</value>
        </entry>
        <entry>
            <key>SW_PARAMETER_CH_LABEL</key>
        </entry>
    </values>
</channel>

How can I obtain the value of key SRV_PARAM_CH_ENABLED if the key is present?
I am using xml.dom.minidom and am able to read up to the channel using:
import xml.dom.minidom

xml_doc = xml.dom.minidom.parse(path)
root = xml_doc.documentElement

chns = xml_doc.getElementsByTagName('channel')

for chn in chns:
   idxx = chn.getElementsByTagName('index')
   idx = idxx[0].childNodes[0].data # Gets ch number


but am stumped after that.

Can you use xml.etree.ElementTree rather than xml.dom.minidom or perhaps https://pypi.org/project/lxml/

Get the values tag, get each of its entry children, get the child's key tag, and if it is equal to the key you want, get the value tag.  What is the difficulty?

@JonSG yes, am open to other libraries

Check out using xml.etree.ElementTree and xpath here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12815637/python-minidom-xml-query

@JonSG thanks for the suggestion, but the examples aren't particularly clear to me

If you search the text of the key-tags you can do:
import xml.dom.minidom

xml_doc = xml.dom.minidom.parse("example.xml")
root = xml_doc.documentElement

keys = root.getElementsByTagName('key')

# all values in your example
for t in keys:
    print(t.firstChild.nodeValue)

# or only the first element
print(keys[0].firstChild.nodeValue)

Output:
SRV_PARAM_CH_ENABLED
SW_PARAMETER_CH_LABEL

SRV_PARAM_CH_ENABLED



If you search the value-tag name if exists and xml.etree.ElementTree is possible for you:
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

root = ET.parse("example.xml").getroot()

d = {}
if root.find(".//entry[key='SRV_PARAM_CH_ENABLED']") is not None:
    d[root.find(".//entry[key='SRV_PARAM_CH_ENABLED']/key").text] = root.find(".//entry[key='SRV_PARAM_CH_ENABLED']/value").text

print(d)

Output:
{'SRV_PARAM_CH_ENABLED': 'false'}

PS: You can find the doc

I hacked out the following.
            xml_doc = xml.dom.minidom.parse(self.fullXmlName) # Parse the XML file
            
            root = xml_doc.documentElement # Get the root element
            chns = xml_doc.getElementsByTagName('channel')
    
            chCheck = {}
    
            for chn in chns:
                idxx = chn.getElementsByTagName('index')
                idx = idxx[0].childNodes[0].data # Gets ch number
                chCheck[idx] = True

                vals = chn.getElementsByTagName('values')
                for val in vals: 
                    entries = val.getElementsByTagName('entry')
                    for entr in entries:
                        if ('SRV_PARAM_CH_ENABLED' in entr.toxml()) and ('false' in entr.toxml()): chCheck[idx] = False


The last step is just handling text; there is probably a better way.
The output is a dictionary of channel numbers that are either on or off.

Just see below example which will help you retrieving the said key - SRV_PARAM_CH_ENABLED.


from xml.dom import minidom

xml_content = """your xml content"""

doc = minidom.parseString(xml_content)

index = doc.getElementsByTagName("index")[0].firstChild.data
print("Index:", index)

entries = doc.getElementsByTagName("entry")

for entry in entries:
    key = entry.getElementsByTagName("key")[0].firstChild.data
    value_node = entry.getElementsByTagName("value")
    
    if value_node: 
        value = value_node[0].firstChild.data
        xsi_type = value_node[0].getAttribute("xsi:type")
        print(f"Key: {key}, Value: {value}, Type: {xsi_type}")
    else:
        print(f"Key: {key}, Value: None")



